# Sporadic server error 502 bad gateway

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the error message:

"502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server."

I have this ReportService that im consuming from code behind in C# like this:

```
string Uri = "report service url"
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(Uri);
string reportKey = "report to be called";
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = reportKey ;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters("some more url parameters for the report");
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
ReportViewer1.PageCountMode = PageCountMode.Actual;
```

And is displayed like this:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer 
    ID="ReportViewer1" 
    runat="server" 
    ProcessingMode="Remote" 
    AsyncRendering="true"
    SizeToReportContent="True"
    ShowRefreshButton="True" 
    ExportContentDisposition="AlwaysAttachment"
    ShowBackButton="False"
    BackColor="White">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

I have been looking around for this scenario, there is sure a lot of topics about the 502 error but none had worked for me so far.
Any suggestions of where to look at?

Comment: Unless you wrote proxy yourself it is unlikely programming issue - proxies (as any other remote servers) are expected to fail randomly... Talking to/working as network admin about proxies on the path to server you working with to is probably what you need.

Comment: Apparently, there isn't an experienced network admin to talk with, is there a test scenario or something i could tell him to do to check this out?

Comment: serverfault.com is probably good place for such question. I'd at least try to find who own the proxy that reports errors (`tracert` command may be enough) and if you can bypass proxy/use another one to see if you are getting failures from actual server or due to proxy config.